# DebugDiag2.0 failed when analyzing the hang issue of asp.net app

Tags: debugdiag

I am using DebugDiag2.0 to analyze the hang issue of asp.net app.
But I got an error:

```
CrashHangAnalysis Failed Dump File:  E:\w3wp_141218.dmp;

Type:  System.FormatException

Message:  the input string format is not correct.

Stack Trace:
at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
at DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.AnalyzeManagedImpl.getDotNetAnalysis(ScriptThreadClass Thread, Object FrameID)
at DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.AnalyzeThreads.getDotNetAnalysisIfThreadMatches(ScriptThreadClass Thread, AnalyzedThreadClass& AnalyzedThread, Int32& nFrameNum)
at DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.AnalyzeThreads.getAnalysis(ScriptThreadClass Thread)
at DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.AnalyzeThreads.DoAnalyzeThreads()
at DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.CrashHangAnalysis.DoHangAnalysis()
at DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.CrashHangAnalysis.RunAnalysisRule(NetScriptManager manager, NetProgress progress)
at DebugDiag.DotNet.NetAnalyzer.RunAnalysisRulesInternal(DumpFileType bitness, NetProgress progress, String symbolPath, String imagePath, String reportFileFullPath, Boolean twoTabs,
```

Could anyone help to know what happened?

I install DebugDiag1.2 to debug the dump file.
I got the error: vbscript runtime error. code is 0x800a000d, type mismatch  'CInt' Line 14896, Column 16 at CrashHangAnalysis.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try to install version 2.0.1:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42933
and try there.

Comment: I think I have installed the update 1. I tried the latesd version, but it still failed.

Comment: I think I have installed the update 1. I tried the latesd version, but it still failed.